# May a Jewish actor playing a role swear "falsely"?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, nedarim-shevuot, emes-truth-honesty, performance-entertainment

Avraham the Jew from New Jersey puts on a costume, takes off his head covering, walks onto a stage, or movie set ... *action*! And says "I, John Jacob Schmidt of Oklahoma, do solemnly swear that I saw that man commit murder." Of course it's all fiction, and everyone knows that. Is that a problem? What if they say "do you swear to God?" What if the prop Bible is an actual Christian Bible?

Comment: There are some mishnayos in nedarim that start with קונם without an explicit האומר

Comment: He could declare before witnesses before going on stage that everything on stage is not real or binding (מסירת מודעה)